# How to expose a MySQL database as OData

Tags: mysql, xml, database, odata

I currently have a mySQL database and want interact with it using OData.

In other words, I want to expose the data in this form:
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

I've found several tutorials on how to do this (for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_buildingappandservicesusingodatavs2010_topic3.aspx) if I have Microsoft Visual Studio. But I'm a mac girl. :(

I've also looked at the libraries at the odata homepage (under libraries, and then mysql). But I can't get them to work.

Is there any easy SIMPLE library that can handle this for me?

Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: Well the one from OData already seems to be quite simple and easy, and by quickly reading the [4-steps tutorial](http://odatamysqlphpconnect.codeplex.com/), I don't believe it is possible to be simpler than that. Perhaps you should rather tell us where you are stuck at.

Comment: When going through the OData PHP Producer Library User Guide, I'm unable to find the QueryProvider.php file anywhere (in the installed code or on my XAMPP server). There is NorthwindQueryProvider, WordPressQueryProvider, and IDataServiceProvider...

Comment: If you are referring to page 67, this must be a typo. The previous paragraph talks about configuring a file named NorthWindQueryProvider.php for IIS. So I would I would try this file. I think they got mixed between NorthWind and WordPress. I would replace all references to "WordPress" by "NorthWind". Oh and by the way, I now realise the 4-step tutorial actually refers to a 70-page manual... Not quite the same indeed.

Comment: Ah - that it's a typo makes sense. So I've done that and struggled to step 3. But when I call (php MySQLConnector.php...) I get an "Error: include_once(Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory..!!!" error when I KNOW DoctrineDBAL is installed. I don't want to say this after all the work to get to step 3, but I don't think OData's "4-Step" process is going to work. It's just been one issue after another.... I'm actually quite surprised the OData website suggests this "connector".

Comment: I just found this copyright notice on one of the pages:  February 19, 2013  Microsoft Open Technologies Inc. I wouldn't be surprised if MS have modified the functionality, and forgotten to tell anyone about it! Combined with the fact that there have been no code comits on the github page for over a year! I'm not really an MS hater, but this is what I don't like about the 'standards' they produce, just have a look at the 'officeOpen' XML standard, which they produced, and now actively don't attempt to align thier output with.

Comment: What is the purpose of using OData? Is this a requirement eg. a third party application you want to communicate with? I have never heard of this format, and yes it looks like yet another Microsoft pseudo protocol. If OData is not an absolute requirement, I would seriously consider a more widely spread protocol, one that you are likely to receive more support with.

Comment: Since there are no other suggestions may be this PHP library will help: [MySQL OData](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlodata/).

Comment: YaK, could you suggest a better protocol alternative?

Comment: @AdamCasey It really depends on the requirements, but if you are just trying to expose some data from a table, a simple JSON-encoded response could do. For a more complex architecture, the SOAP protocol is a good candidate.

Comment: YaK, our requirements are to do CRUD from multiple endpoint across different platforms.  I want a cross platform standardized way to access a database on a server, without writing my own code to do so.

Comment: @YaK yes indeed, of course.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it - using [odata4j](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/). 
I've documented my steps below in case anyone else wants to do something similar.

You will need to:

- generate a JPA model from your database
- use odata4j's NorthwindJpaProducerExample.java script

Detailed steps are below:

1. Odata4j is an open-source Odata Producer/Consumer in Java. Therefore, you will need to **set up Eclipse for EE Developers with a database**. I suggest [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_644392&feature=iv&src_vid=R7B5T3H2I5A&v=UQJKkqqiVDo) tutorial if you are new to Eclipse.
2. Follow [these](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.samptut.doc/tutorials/javaee/topics/lesson1.4.html) instructions to generate a JPA model.
3. Go to Odata4j and download the latest archive zip
4. Add odata4j-bundle-x.x.jar to your build path (it is found in the bundles file).
5. Insert the following scripts from Odata4j, found on their github: NorthwindJpaProducerExample, JPAProvider, and DatabaseUtils (requires [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)). (To be honest, I just copy and pasted them into Eclipse). At this point, your Project Explorer bar should look like this (without model.main):

[image: Project Explorer Bar]

At this point, right-click the project and select Build Path > Configure Build Path. Add the following "External Jars" from your Odata4j archive file.

[image: External Jars]

Now edit the code in NorthwindJpaProducerExample in the following ways:

1. Change the string "endpointUri" to whatever url you want the oData at
2. Change the string "persistenceUnitName" to the name of your entity in persistence.xml (as you can in the image above, mine was called "createJPA".)

[image: code sample in NorthwindJpaProducerExample]

And then you have OData!

[image: My OData]

I ran in to a couple problems while following these steps and will document them here in case you have them also.

- In order to successfully follow step 2 (generate JPA) each table MUST have a primary key. Do it - I'm not joking.
- After editing the code, I had a "BigInteger" error. JPAProducer does not support bigInteger field types. Go back to your database and change the size of your column to a regular int.
- After changing your database in ANY manner, make sure to refresh you database and to clean the project. This will make you and Eclipse happy.
- I don't think this will be necessary for everyone, but I did need to add a HyperSQL driver dependency. If you get a HSQL error, go to [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/hsqldb/) and get the latest stable version. Add the hsqldb.jar to your Build Path.

Not SUPER easy, but a lot better than a 70+ page manual.

Comment: Just a note, the ODataContext interface seems to be missing the jar files provided from gitHub (eclipse produces a "can't resolve to a type" error), though the source is still listed there: https://github.com/odata4j/odata4j/blob/master/odata4j-core/src/main/java/org/odata4j/producer/ODataContext.java

Comment: The same is true for an interface required by that, ODataHeadersContext.java found at https://github.com/odata4j/odata4j/blob/master/odata4j-core/src/main/java/org/odata4j/producer/ODataHeadersContext.java . . I have not yet determined why they have been removed from javadoc and distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems odata4j does not support compound keys in tables. I got all the way through this to the point where the exception "IdClass not yet supported", which you can find jpa producer JPA Edm Generator:  https://github.com/vorburger/odata4j/blob/master/odata4j-core/src/main/java/org/odata4j/producer/jpa/JPAEdmGenerator.java

Comment: Just curious to know, did you find any other better approach than this, as this thread is 3 years old.

Comment: Did you try using an OData service like [DataDirect Cloud](https://www.progress.com/cloud-data-integration) or [Hybrid Data Pipeline](https://www.progress.com/hybrid-data-integration) .You can learn about this service at: [DataDirect OData](https://www.progress.com/odata)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another alternative for you. Using [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/connect/mysql-odata) is a no-coding, cloud solution to expose your MySQL database as OData.

Here’s how:

First, create a connection to your MySQL database.

[image]

Then, create an endpoint. A wizard will guide you through the rest of the configuration.

[image]

Select the MySQL connection you created earlier and select the tables you need. Then, configure security. Finally, an endpoint URL will be provided for you.

That’s it. For more details, check out this [link](https://skyvia.com/connect/mysql-odata).