# How to access MySQL from anywhere around the world through Internet

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I am new using MySQL. I would like to connect to MySQL DB from anywhere via internet using my  IP Address, username and password.

To bring it in context, I was previously using **AWS RDS** (MySQL Engine) which provided a link, username and password and was able to remotely access my DB in NodeJs. However, the cost was a bit high so I wanted to replicate this. Hence, I decided to host the DB locally on PC/Server and would like **to access the DB remotely via Internet so I can link it to my NodeJs backend server.**

[Update]:

I tried playing with inbound and outbound rules to allow all connection to MySQL DB.
To test it, I was able to successfully connect to the db from another computer if on the same Wifi but when I change wifi or connect from another location the connection to the DB did not work.

Comment: You don't **and you shouldn't**. Never expose DB servers directly to the Internet.

Comment: _"Hence, I decided to host the DB locally on PC/Server"_ - that won't work because you're presumably behind a NAT _and_ have a dynamic IP address, so it won't be possible to clients to reliably connect directly to your server instance. Self-hosting isn't feasible unless you have IPv6 (to avoid NAT) _and_ have a static (or at least "sticky") address (so cached DNS will resolve correctly; IPv6 is _intended_ to be "hidden" behind DNS rather than having users directly use IPv6 addresses).

Comment: I do have IPv6
Any tutorial you can suggest or guide?

Comment: Even if you're using IPv6 you **should not** expose a DB server - it's simple as that. I wont' help you with _doing the wrong thing_. The right-thing-to-do is to expose the data via an intermediate web-service which is where you can have your business/security/etc logic - in a pinch you can use OData, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990252/how-to-expose-a-mysql-database-as-odata

Comment: Also, even if you have IPv6 there is no gurantee that remote-clients can connect using IPv6 - lots of people (myself included) are still on IPv4-only home Internet connections. Until IPv6 hits critical-mass (and desirable services become IPv6-only) you'll _need_ to run things on a "dual-stack" basis.

Comment: Exposing DB is a terrible idea definetly. Still making connection to DB available over VPN or an SSH tunnel is still an option in some cases. But it kills performance and never should be used in production.

Comment: @Jared, in production what would be a good solution to connect a NodeJs server to a SQL DB that is on My PC remotely. Without using a third party like AWS RDS (cost being the main drawbac). If that's even possible ?

Comment: Start with RDMS and application running at the same host. For small to medium projects performance might be quite fine. Otherwise there's a number of methods to increase it. If you need your app to be publicly available, cheap VPS might be a solution.